# Trying to adapt Menu Icon to Mojave dark mode

Tags: icons, macos-mojave

After switching to mojave I´m trying to adapt the menu icon when the mode has changed.
My app: "Application is agent (UIElement)" doesn´t have windows initially.

At the moment I´m using the NSMenuDelegate function **menuWillOpen** which works so far but the user has to open the menu to get the icon changed.

I wonder if there is a way to detect that the appearance has changed whithout opening  the menu. I already tried applicationDidChangeScreenParameters from NSApplicationDelegate without success.

//this comes from NSMenuDelegate

```
- (void)menuWillOpen:(NSMenu *)menu { 
    [self adaptToDarkMode];
}
```

// this handles the menu icon change

```
 - (void) adaptMenuIcon {
    BOOL  darkModeFlag  = [self psGetDarkMode];
    NSString *iconName  = @"MenuIconBlack";

    if(darkModeFlag) {
        iconName  = @"MenuIconWhite";
    }

    NSString *filePath  = [self psBundlePathToFolder:@""];
    NSString *finalPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@.png", filePath, iconName];

    NSImage  *image     = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
    pathToMenuIcons     = [self psBundlePathToFolder:@"MenuIcons"];

    [statusItem setMenu:statusMenu];
    [statusItem setTitle:@"➜"];
    [statusItem setImage: image];
    [statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
}
```

[image: The main Menu]

Answer (score 0):

You can read global preferences:

```
NSString *appearance = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"AppleInterfaceStyle"];
```

This will return `Dark` in dark mode.

You can also use `NSDistributedNotificationCenter`

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onAppearanceChanged:) name:@"AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification" object:nil]

-(void)onAppearanceChanged:(NSNotification *)notificaton
{
 // read appearance
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it always returns "Light" no matter what´s turned on. Even after reboot. At the moment I´m using "defaults read NSGlobalDomain AppleInterfaceStyle" which workes fine. Any idea?

Comment: Its working fine for me. You can try NSDictionary *dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] persistentDomainForName:NSGlobalDomain];
id appearance = [dict objectForKey:@"AppleInterfaceStyle"];. Its same as above code.